# Cleanly stop processes and exit when a Tkinter widget is closed

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a Python 3.11.5 program that uses a Tkinter GUI to receive user input, and runs a number of processes in the background. I'm wondering what the preferred method is for handling when the user wants to cancel a background process while it's still running. I've tried to make cancel buttons, to use separate threads and `threading.Event`s to signal a cancel, but I can't get it to exit cleanly. I'd like to be able to hit cancel, take a couple seconds if needed, but see the program end and my terminal go back to normal, with no errors.

Here's a minimum example:

```py
import tkinter as tk
import time

class app(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.title("An app")
        self.create_widgets()
        self.a_process()

    def create_widgets(self):
        self.text = tk.Label(self, text = "Hello World!")
        self.text.pack()
        self.cancelButton = tk.Button(self, text = "Cancel", command = self.destroy)
        self.cancelButton.pack()

    def a_process(self):
        for i in range(100):
            self.text.config(text = f"Message # {i}")
            self.text.update()
            time.sleep(1)

    def destroy(self):
        super().destroy()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = app()
    root.mainloop()
```

Hitting cancel while the message loop is running gives this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\M.Modeler\geoSieve 1.1\test.py", line 27, in <module>
    root = app()
           ^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\M.Modeler\geoSieve 1.1\test.py", line 9, in __init__
    self.a_process()
  File "C:\Users\M.Modeler\geoSieve 1.1\test.py", line 19, in a_process
    self.text.config(text = f"Message # {i}")
  File "C:\Users\M.Modeler\AppData\Local\miniconda3\envs\geoSieve\Lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1702, in configure
    return self._configure('configure', cnf, kw)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\M.Modeler\AppData\Local\miniconda3\envs\geoSieve\Lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1692, in _configure
    self.tk.call(_flatten((self._w, cmd)) + self._options(cnf))
_tkinter.TclError: invalid command name ".!label"
```

What is my `destroy` method missing to end the background process and exit cleanly?

Comment: check tekinter version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you shouldn't be using a blocking infinite loop in your GUI, instead use `self.after` to schedule a function to be called later, now you don't need to call `update` to redraw the GUI, and as a side-bonus when the GUI exits the function won't be called anymore.

```
import tkinter as tk
import time

class app(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.title("An app")
        self.create_widgets()
        self.after(1000, lambda: self.a_process(0))

    def create_widgets(self):
        self.text = tk.Label(self, text = "Hello World!")
        self.text.pack()
        self.cancelButton = tk.Button(self, text = "Cancel", command = self.destroy)
        self.cancelButton.pack()

    def a_process(self, i):
        self.text.config(text = f"Message # {i}")
        if i+1 < 100:  # call this function later with different args
            self.after(1000,lambda: self.a_process(i+1))

    def destroy(self):
        super().destroy()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = app()
    root.mainloop()
```

alternatively if you have a long task that you want to run in the background you could schedule it on a `threading.Thread` that is daemon (will terminate when python exits), and have it call `self.after` on a function that updates the GUI.

as functions called with `after` won't happen when your mainloop ends, you won't be trying to update the GUI when the GUI exits.

```py
import tkinter as tk
import time
import threading

class app(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.title("An app")
        self.create_widgets()
        self.counter = 0
        thread = threading.Thread(target = self.a_process, args=[], daemon=True)
        thread.start()
        
    def create_widgets(self):
        self.text = tk.Label(self, text = "Hello World!")
        self.text.pack()
        self.cancelButton = tk.Button(self, text = "Cancel", command = self.destroy)
        self.cancelButton.pack()

    def a_process(self):
        for i in range(100):
            self.counter += 1
            self.after(0,self.update_counter)
            time.sleep(1)
            
    def update_counter(self):
        self.text.config(text = f"Message # {self.counter}")

    def destroy(self):
        super().destroy()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = app()
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: thanks, this is cool- basically using the main loop to accomplish the looping, rather than a loop within a method. A more complex example might include a function call within the method, where the function has some loops that run within it. In that case, would be best approach be to re-write the code to operate like this, taking the guts of the foreign function and making it a method of this class `app`? Or is there another approach where I can call foreign functions, and cancel their loops from the GUI? I can add another example to the question if needed.

Comment: @bt3 check the added code, the trick here is that `after` function won't execute after the mainloop ends, so use it for GUI updates, and keep the looping logic in its own thread away from the GUI updates.

Comment: Btw `lambda: self.a_process()` can be simplified to just `self.a_process`, and `self.after(1000,lambda: self.a_process(i+1))` into `self.after(1000, self.a_process, i+1)` and the `def destroy(self): super().destroy()` can be removed. Also avoid calling `tkinter` methods from threads other than the one where you created the `tk.Tk`. In some rare cases it can cause problems.

Comment: @TheLizzard you are right about the simplification part (which i never seem to remember in practice), but using `after` to update the GUI is threadsafe, and ensures the updates happen in the GUI thread, and is the correct way to do GUI updates (next to custom events).

Comment: @AhmedAEK Yes in theory that is right. But in practice there are other methods that you aren't threadsafe like `__del__` which is called when the object is being garbage collected. So in a lot of cases like [this one](https://pastebin.com/wF5Fn19a), it's not easy to see what the actual problem is. So it's best to avoid calling `tkinter` from multiple threads.

Comment: @TheLizzard this bug is not caused by calling tkinter from another thread, its caused by tkinter being reachable from another thread, which is a much bigger problem to avoid, i would say this bug is enough to avoid using tkinter as its most basic operation is bugged, yet again i have made a lot of GUI apps with tkinter that do a lot more than just logging when the GUI terminates, so i am surprised to see this bug.

Comment: @AhmedAEK If you call a `tkinter` method then `tkinter` must be reachable so that bug may present. That is why I separate all of the `tkinter` stuff from the `threading` stuff and avoid that problem for the most part. I use `tkinter` because I can't set up any other GUI framework :D.

Comment: @AhmedAEK @TheLizzard Thanks both for the input, `tkinter` and `threading` have been a major source of confusion for me. The second code that uses `threading` exits cleanly for me, and adding `daemon = True` within the thread instances in my huge program seems to have cleaned up the exits nicely.